# About real-valued function

Tags: functions

If $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p\in [1,\infty)$, then is it true that $|f(x)+g(x)|^p=|f(x)|^p+|g(x)|^p$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Is "for any"="for some" or "for every"? (Incidentally, it doesn't matter to answer the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. At any $x$, since $f(x)g(x)=0$, at least one of $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is zero. If $f(x)$ is zero, then
$$
|f(x)+g(x)|^p=|g(x)|^p=|f(x)|^p+|g(x)|^p
$$
and the similar holds in the other case.

Comment: Wow, it is trivial... Thanks!